# Split data set in fixed interval batches, while getting the first and last row of the batch

Tags: sql, postgresql, sliding-window

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
id name value timestamp
1 Indicator1 5 "2021-07-06 20:28:59.999+03"
2 Indicator1 6 "2021-07-06 20:29:59.999+03"
3 Indicator1 14 "2021-07-06 20:30:59.999+03"
4 Indicator2 1 "2021-07-06 20:31:59.999+03"
5 Indicator2 3 "2021-07-06 20:32:59.999+03"
etc
```

The timestamps are 1 minute apart.

What I would like to get out of this data set is groups of rows which correspond to, let's say 5 minute intervals and while doing so get the first and last value/row in each group. I have to calculate some differences in values over fixed time intervals. It's sort of like a k-line.

What I managed so far is to get only the first interval and then repeat this query to get subsequent (older intervals) with a different where clause:

```
select r.name,
        r.value_end - r.value_start as value_increase,
        interval '5 min' as time_interval
from 
(select k.name, 
        FIRST_VALUE(k.value) over w as value_start, 
        LAST_VALUE(k.value) over w as value_end,
        ROW_NUMBER() over w as rownum
from dataset k
where k.timestamp >= (now() - interval '5 min')
window w as (partition by k.name order by k.timestamp RANGE BETWEEN 
            UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 
            UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)) as r
where r.rownum = 1
```

Is there a way of doing this with Postgres?

Comment: are the timestamps guaranteed to always be 1 minute apart (or do we have to check for this?) ?  if so couldn't you just assign a row number to each record order by it and then use mod X  with no remainder to get your intervals?

Comment: You're right, @xQbert, they are not always 1 minute apart. I didn't give that much thought since I applied the solution in the question. Interesting approach with mod X, nevertheless. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to do is assign a grouping to timestamps in five minutes.  Instead of fiddling with timestamp arithmetic, one method is to use epoch time and some arithmetic:

```
select min(timestamp), max(timestamp),
       min(case when seqnum = 1 then value end) value_first,
       min(case when seqnum = cnt then value end) value_last
from (select d.*, v.m,
             row_number() over (partition by v.m order by timestamp) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by v.m) as cnt
      from dataset d cross join lateral
           (values (floor(extract(epoch from d.timestamp) / (24 * 60 * 12))
           ) v(m)
     ) t
group by v.m;
```